# How to delete folder (and its content) not under storage/app in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5, laravel-storage

I know we can use Storage::delete() or File::delete to delete folders and/or files in laravel, but this seems not working for folders directly under storage, I mean storage/tmp by example. It only works for storage/app.
How to deal with this?

```
if (file_exists( storage_path() . '/tmp/file1'.'.pdf' )) {
     File::delete(storage_path() . '/tmp/file1'.'.pdf') );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "Seems not working" is pretty broad. Can you share the code in question, and your debugging attempts?

Comment: `File::delete` should work everywhere. `Storage::delete` only works on filesystems such as public or s3

Answer (score 5):

You can define a new disk in `config/filesystems.php` with the storage folder as root:

```
'disks' => [

    ...

    'storage' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path(),
    ],

    ...

],
```

Then you can delete a folder, such as `tmp`, like this:

```
Storage::disk('storage')->deleteDirectory('tmp');
```

Comment: Disk [storage] does not have a configured driver. Is it missing 'tmp' in storage_path()?

Comment: Did you configure the disk with the driver and root in `config/filesystems.php`, as shown in the example of this answer?

Comment: That's strange, because the `local` driver should be available when specified as driver for the `storage` disk. When the `tmp` folder does not exist, the above statement will return `false` instead of `true`, so that shouldn't be a problem. After adding the disk to your config and running `php artisan config:clear` this really should work.

Answer (score 0):

that happen due you have the default configuration in filesystems config, go to config folder
`config/filesystems.php`

and in the `disk` property you can modify or add a new key

When you use the Storage directly without call the disk method Laravel will use the default disk called 'local'

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
     ]
```

How you can see the root key start in app folder, so when you use Storage::delete() always will delete all inside app folder, the solution can be alter de root key of local disk

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path(),
     ]
```

Of this way now when you call the Storage the root will by storage path directly, but the best way its add a new key and don't overwrite the default config

```
'disks' => [
    'storage' => [
        'driver' => 'storage',
        'root' => storage_path(),
     ]
```

And now you can use the new disk of this way:

```
Storage::disk('storage')->delete('x')
```